sf intersection with osmdata failing
I'm trying to extract data from osm to use in an anlysis, but I'm having trouble with sf::st_intersection. Reprex below,
# load libraries
library(osmdata)

# osmdata
co = opq_osm_id(type = "relation", id = "6077602") |> 
  opq_string() |> 
  osmdata_sf()

# interested in multipolygon
co_multipoly = co$osm_multipolygons |>
  sf::st_transform(3857)

# bounding box to extract osmdata
bbox = data.frame(x = c(-8664207, -8664207, -8663609, -8663609), y = c(4807913, 4808799, 4808799, 4807913), name = 'bbox') |> 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y'), crs = 3857) |>
  dplyr::group_by(name) |>
  dplyr::summarize(do_union = FALSE) |>
  sf::st_cast('POLYGON')

# they intersect
plot(bbox$geometry)
plot(co_multipoly$geometry, add = TRUE, col = 'orange')

# but sf::st_intersection fails
sf::st_intersection(co_multipoly$geometry, bbox$geometry)
Geometry set for 0 features 
Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator

What am I doing wrong?

After performing your call to sf::st_transform(), if you call st_is_valid(co_multipoly, reason = TRUE), you will see that the geometry for co_multipoly is no longer valid due to "Hole lies outside shell".  You can pass co_multipoly to st_make_valid() to correct this.  As to why your geometry is no longer valid after calling st_transform(), I am not certain.  Perhaps because you are switching between a geographic and projected CRS...

@edixon1, thanks! It would be helpful if sf::st_intersection threw an error in this case, but oh well. I'll be on the look out for this (invalid geometry) moving forward when performing spatial intersections.
